# How to find the norm of a vector if the definition of the inner product is not given?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

I'm not really sure with this question because whenever these kinds of problems appears, it always comes with an integrals definition of the inner product but this time we are only given this:

$$ x(t) = x_{1}t^{2} + x_{1}t + x_{0} $$
$$ y(t) = y_{1}t^{2} + y_{1}t + y_{0} $$

in P<sub>2</sub>[t], defined
$$ <x(t),y(t)> = x_{2}y_{2} + x_{1}y_{1} + 3x_{0}y_{0} $$

Then the question is that if
$ x(t) = t^{2}-2, y(t) = t+1,s(t)= 3t^{2} -t$

compute for $||x(t)||$. What do I do with the the definition of $<x(t),y(t)>$ to solve this probem? Or i dont think for this problem? I'm thinking of writing x(t) in coordinate vectors by using a standard basis for P2[t] then from that solve the length using this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBLWF.png)

Edit:  I just realized the image I attached above is the dot product.

Comment: As you have not told us what $p(t)$ is the question is not doable.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician Sorry I forgot to change the letters i used. Ill edit it

Comment: So $\langle x, x\rangle= 1\cdot 1+0\cdot 0+3 ((-2)\cdot (-2)=$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Ohhhhhhhhhhh, i get it know holy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of the norm of an inner-product space,

$\|p(t)\| = \sqrt{\langle p(t),p(t)\rangle}$.

Comment: I know that but what I don't understand where will I get the definition of the inner product with the integrals?

Comment: This one is not defined by integrals, is it?

Comment: Its not. I haven't encountered a problem like this so I dont know where to start

Comment: You have stated a formula for the inner product, this tells you how to use that to get the length: what is your problem?